# Excel VBA - Creating a textbox that fills the active cell

Tags: excel, vba, basic

I want to create a macro, that inputs a string into the next available cell, in a defined row. So when the next available cell is found, a inputbox appears, the user types in the data, and then the data goes into the active cell.

I currently have this:

```
Sub Find_Blank_Row()
Dim QtyInput As String
Dim BlankRow As Long
BlankRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Cells(BlankRow, 1).Select
QtyInput = InputBox("please Enter Company Name")
ActiveRow.Font.Bold = True
ActiveSheet.Range("ActiveCell").Value = QtyEntry
End Sub
```

How do I make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answerL

```
 Sub Find_Blank_Row()
 Dim QtyInput As String
 Dim BlankRow As Long
 BlankRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
 QtyInput = InputBox("Please Enter Company Name")
 Cells(BlankRow, 1).Font.Bold = True
 Cells(BlankRow, 1).Value = QtyInput
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ActiveCell` is an object itself always defined at run-time, not the name of a `Range` object. You should replace this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("ActiveCell").Value = QtyEntry
```

with this

```
ActiveCell.Value = QtyEntry '<-- ActiveCell is an object pointed through the variable "ActiveCell"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to Select to place the value:

```
Sub Find_Blank_Row()

    Dim QtyInput As String

    QtyInput = InputBox("please Enter Company Name")

    With Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Value = QtyEntry
    End With

End Sub
```